# How to create an SDL pop up menu?

Tags: c++, user-interface, menu, sdl

I've seached around how to create a pop up menu in a SDL window application using c++ ? I haven't found any clues !

I would like to have something that looks like this : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mc_CE9OiHvA

I've tried to use glutMenu, but it doesn't work ...

Thanks

Comment: You could make your own class. That's what I did. Make it draw and handle events through SDL. Use rectangles and all that to check for clicks. It's good practice, and if it doesn't work out you could find some other SDL specific or generic GUI library out there. On a side note, glutMenu doesn't work unless you setup SDL for OpenGL rendering, which is a whole different chapter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SDL is a low-level graphics library.  I don't remember seeing anything like menus, buttons, or other GUI controls in it last time I used it.  It's possible that one of the many [add-on libraries](http://www.libsdl.org/libraries.php) has menuing functions.  Generally, you're expected to build such things yourself from primitives SDL provides.

One add-on library you might want to get is [SDL_ttf](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/), for drawing text using TrueType fonts.  That and a few lines and mouse handers, *et voilà*, you have a menu.

Answer (score 0):

SDL itself doesn't have any GUI libraries. That video looks like a guy who used SDL to write his own GUI using graphic primitive and font calls.

There are several SDL GUI libraries referenced on http://www.libsdl.org/libraries.php

How usable they are, I have no idea.